# What is the effect of DNS ttl on established TCP connections

Tags: tcp, dns, ttl

Say I do a DNS dip from my "client" to initiate a TCP connection with server.example.com.
Say that the IP address for server.example.com resolves to 1.1.1.1 with a ttl of 300 seconds.

Now say that I successfully setup a TCP connection to server.example.com (at 1.1.1.1 based on the DNS lookup).
Now when the 300 seconds expires and the DNS record is expunged from my local cache, what happens to my EXISTING TCP connection?

I understand that if I try to setup another TCP connection to server.example.com, it will do another DNS dip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens to my EXISTING TCP connection?

Nothing. It's established. It has no further need for DNS.